# Is spring AOP active when I schedule method reference with @Transactional annotation

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, transactions

Having the code at the bottom we've encountered a problem with Hibernate Session like below. ( An entity that has getter throws that )

We suspect that it is related to `@Transactional` annotation not beeing processed since doSomething is not called by proxy object.

Could it be possible that code like this won't process annotation ?

Our AOP config for transactional:

```
<tx:annotation-driven transaction-manager="transactionManager" />
```

```
org.hibernate.LazyInitializationException: could not initialize proxy - no Session
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.initialize(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:146)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.AbstractLazyInitializer.getImplementation(AbstractLazyInitializer.java:259)
        at org.hibernate.proxy.pojo.javassist.JavassistLazyInitializer.invoke(JavassistLazyInitializer.java:73)
```

```
@Autowired
private TaskScheduler taskScheduler;

private ScheduledFuture future;

@PostConstruct
public void init() {
    schedule();
}

private void schedule() {
    if (future != null) {
        future.cancel(false);
    }
    final String cronTriggerValue = "CRON_VALUE_FROM_DB._MUST_BE_FROM_DB";
    future = taskScheduler.schedule(this::doSomething, new CronTrigger(cronTriggerValue));
}

@Transactional
@Caching(evict = { @CacheEvict(value = "someValue", allEntries = true) })
public void doSomething() {
}
```

Comment: What proxy type you're using?

Comment: @M.Prokhorov I've updated the question

Comment: Spring uses proxies to apply AOP, you are doing an internal method calls which doesn't pass through the proxy. Hence this doesn't work. The sample applies to the `@Caching` that doesn't work either.

Comment: move doSomething method to an separated service, then inject it in your Component.